# How to avoid braces on a separate line in a try/catch block using checkstyle format command

Tags: java, try-catch, checkstyle

Format command from checkstyle plugin wraps "}" on a separate line for a try/catch block, how do I prevent this on format. Tried using various options from RightCurly but it didn't make a difference . Refer https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_blocks.html

```
-        } catch (IOException ioe) {
+        }
+        catch (IOException ioe) {
```

Note: I want it to be retained like this `} catch (IOException ioe) {`

Answer (score 0):

Just `RightCurly` without parameters won't do. You'll have to provide the tokens before which you require a right curly brace.
Example:

```
<module name="RightCurly">
    <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_TRY, LITERAL_CATCH, LITERAL_FINALLY, LITERAL_IF, LITERAL_ELSE"/>
</module>
```

For a full checkstyle configuration including this code, see [this project](https://github.com/Pieter12345/JavaLoader/blob/master/checkstyle.xml#L195-L197).

Comment: I don't see a difference and I was using the same options earlier in checkstyle.xml.

Comment: Do you think disabling RightCurly check would help here?

Comment: If you put a newline between `}` and `catch`, are you getting the expected `[ERROR] <path-to-source-file>: '}' at column 3 should be on the same line as the next part of a multi-block statement (one that directly contains multiple blocks: if/else-if/else, do/while or try/catch/finally). [RightCurly]`?
If this is the case, then the format command from your CS plugin does not respect this setting and in fact generates code with CS violations. I would suggest checking whether their documentation has anything on this and otherwise submit a bug report.